# Collada import crashes in 2.76

Tags: collada

I have issues with some Collada files. 
When I import any of the problematic files, Blender doesn't show anything on stage. There are new objects imported in the scene hierarchy, though. My model has some geometry and a skeleton, and I can see them in the hierarchy. But when I click on the geometry, Blender just crashes.

Both files that work and those that don't work, use the same schema version, 1.4.1,

```
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
```

I checked that the schema is valid (with ruby nokogiri), and I can open the file with other viewers (Open3mod).

Anyone knows if the importer expects a certain ordering of the XML nodes? Where's the source code?